# Google Places auto complete dropdown not clickable in mobile browser

Tags: angularjs, google-places

I have this Angular JS directive for Google Places auto complete and it's working fine. My problem is that when I try it on a mobile browser like Google Chrome or Safari, well mobile, the pac item, .pac container doesn't allow me to click on the drop down. This is my directive:

```
angular.module('wtSharedUtil').directive('googleplace', [ function() {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',

    require : '?ngModel',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
      var options = {
      };
      scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          model.$setViewValue(element.val());

        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I found a jQuery solution, but it is not a good solution:

```
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
      $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('needsclick');
      console.log('disabletap ready')
    }
  }, '.pac-container');
```

This is not ionic, it is just angular. I would like an angular solution.
How can I do that?